android project from github cannot run after imported to android studio
android project from github cannot run after imported to android studio. Consider these scenes below. Comparing to the old eclipse plugin of android development, why android studio cannot automatically fix all these problems so that it can run immediately after import?
Following scenes:
1.
android-audio-visualizer-master
A problem occurred configuring root project 'android-audio-visualizer-master'.

Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':classpath'.
Could not find org.codehaus.groovy.modules.http-builder:http-builder:0.7.2.
Searched in the following locations:
- https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/groovy/modules/http-builder/http-builder/0.7.2/http-builder-0.7.2.pom
- https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/org/codehaus/groovy/modules/http-builder/http-builder/0.7.2/http-builder-0.7.2.pom
- https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/org/codehaus/groovy/modules/http-builder/http-builder/0.7.2/http-builder-0.7.2.pom
Required by:
project : > com.jfrog.bintray.gradle:gradle-bintray-plugin:1.7.3

Possible solution:

Declare repository providing the artifact, see the documentation at https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/declaring_repositories.html

Scene 2:
Simple Voice Recorder
The project is using an incompatible version (AGP 8.1.1) of the Android Gradle plugin. Latest supported version is AGP 8.0.2
See Android Studio & AGP compatibility options.
